# Proof for $\sup\limits_{i_1,i_2,...i_j}|E(X_{i_1}X_{i_2}...X_{i_j})| = E(|X_{1}|^j)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expectation, independence

Let $X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{n} $ be i.i.d such that $E(X_{1})< ∞$.

Let $i_{j}∈\{1,2,...,n\}$ with $j<n$.

Suppose $E(|X_{1}|^j)$ exists.

Could someone give me a proof that

$$\sup_{i_1,i_2,...i_j}|E(X_{i_1}X_{i_2}...X_{i_j})| = E(|X_{1}|^j)\ ?$$

Comment: @saz 14 I am not sure whether this is correct or not. But this statement is used to prove a lemma which is then used to prove a theorem. Could you give me the proof if left-hand side equals $|E(X_{1})|^j$ ?

Comment: @saz OP seems to mean that those index $i_j$ can be repeated. It is interesting to see if the all distinct case is the minimum or not.

Comment: @BGM Yup those index can be repeated.

Comment: It is lemma 5.3.1 from Mathematical Statistics by Peter J Bickel. If this is wong, could someone please suggest me some materials to read through the Chapter "First and Higher Order Asymptotics: The Delta Method with Applications" ?

Comment: Sorry; I missed that the indizes can be repeated.

Comment: If $j=3$ and $E(X_i)=E(X_i^3)=0$ for every $i$, then the supremum in the LHS is $0$ while the RHS is not, thus the assertion you try to prove does not hold in general. Sure you do not want to prove $$\sup_{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_j)}|E(X_{i_1}X_{i_2}\ldots X_{i_j})| \leqslant E(|X_1|^j)$$ instead, or $$\sup_{(i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_j)}E(|X_{i_1}X_{i_2}\ldots X_{i_j}|)| = E(|X_1|^j)\ ?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $c_i \in \{0, 1, \ldots, j\}$, $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$  such that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n c_i = j$. Now the LHS can be expressed as 
$$ \sup_{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n}\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n |X_i|^{c_i}\right]$$

Note that
$$ \mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n |X_i|^{c_i}\right] = \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[ |X_i|^{c_i}\right] 
\leq \prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\left[ |X_i|^{j}\right]^{\frac {c_i} {j}} 
=\mathbb{E}\left[ |X_1|^{j}\right]^{\frac {1} {j}\sum_{i=1}^nc_i}
= \mathbb{E}\left[ |X_1|^{j}\right] $$

where the first equality follows by independence, the inequality is the Jensen's inequality (we apply on those $c_i$ are non-zero, and for those $c_i = 0$, equality holds as both equal to $1$ anyway). The next equality follows by the identical distribution and collecting the like terms, and the last equality follows by the assumption.

Equality holds if and only if there is exactly one of the $c_i = j$ and all others vanish. Since the above statement holds for any arbitrary $c_i$ satisfying the assumption and it is attainable, it is indeed the supremum.

Comment: The question is asking about $$ \sup_{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n}\left|\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n X_i^{c_i}\right]\right|$$ instead of $$ \sup_{c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n}\mathbb{E}\left[\prod_{i=1}^n |X_i|^{c_i}\right]$$

Comment: @BGM I think this should be the correct statement that needs to be proved in the book. Thank you very much.